# Portrait image automatically rotate to landscape, when i upload image into iOS app webview.. Is there any solutions in css code or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swift, twitter-bootstrap

[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEnXm.jpg) I used bootstrap modal popup window for upload image.. please see the html code.

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="avatar-modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="avatar-modal-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <form class="avatar-form" action="crop.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="hdn_qr_sessionid" id="hdn_qr_sessionid" value="<?php echo $qr['qr_session_id'] ; ?>" />
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="avatar-modal-label">Change Background</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="avatar-body">
                          <!-- Upload image and data -->
                          <div class="avatar-upload">
                              <input type="hidden" class="avatar-src" name="avatar_src">
                              <input type="hidden" class="avatar-data" name="avatar_data">
                              <div class="fileUpload btn add_more add_more2">
                                  <span>Upload Image<i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                  <input type="file" class="avatar-input form-control file upload" id="avatarInput" name="avatar_file">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Crop and preview -->
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <div class="avatar-wrapper"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row avatar-btns">
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block avatar-save">Done</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- <div class="modal-footer">              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>            </div> -->
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="avatar-modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="avatar-modal-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">

Comment: It's probably the orientation information in the EXIF header of the image. I don't know of any simple way to identify it using CSS / JavaScript, but you can do it server-side for sure. You have two options:

 - Strip the EXIF data to prevent auto-rotation by Safari / WebKit.
 - Apply the correct orientation directly using an image transform, and then strip the EXIF data.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution in the "Swift (iOS)" based code...?